# categorical_crossentropy loss , no attribute 'get_shape'

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to get categorical_crossentropy loss for my model(for training) which has last layer: `model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))` . so i take output of this layer and use follwing code to get loss output using following code:

```python
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 3
epochs = 1

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x1_train=x_train[y_train==0]; y1_train=y_train[y_train==0]
x1_test=x_test[y_test==0];y1_test=y_test[y_test==0]
x2_train=x_train[y_train==1];y2_train=y_train[y_train==1]
x2_test=x_test[y_test==1];y2_test=y_test[y_test==1]
x3_train=x_train[y_train==2];y3_train=y_train[y_train==2]
x3_test=x_test[y_test==2];y3_test=y_test[y_test==2]

X=np.concatenate((x1_train,x2_train,x3_train,x1_test,x2_test,x3_test),axis=0)
Y=np.concatenate((y1_train,y2_train,y3_train,y1_test,y2_test,y3_test),axis=0)

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y)

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
model.summary()
get_dense_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[3].output])
layer_output = get_dense_layer_output([x_train])[0]
g=K.categorical_crossentropy(layer_output, y_train)
```

and getting error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`. How to solve it.

Comment: where exactly in your code does the error happen?

Comment: g=K.categorical_crossentropy(layer_output, y_train)     in this line

Comment: In the future, it will be a good idea to omit all parts of the code which are irrelevant to the question (here `x1, x2, x3` staff, `Tensorboard`, `confusion_matrix`, `X, Y` etc) - they only serve to make the question look unnecessarily long & may deter potential respondents...

Comment: Sure. I will take care of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all practical purposes, Dr. Snoopy's' answer below is correct.

For educational purposes (or whatever other purposes you may have), here is what is happening with your script & error:

In all Keras loss functions, such as `K.categorical_crossentropy()`, the arguments are tensors (which do have a `get_shape` argument), and not numpy arrays (which do not) - check the [docs](https://keras.io/losses/). So, you should convert your numpy arrays to tensors, but before that, you have to cast them in the same type (they are not), otherwise you will get an error:

```python
y_train.dtype
# dtype('float64')

layer_output.dtype
# dtype('float32')

y_train = y_train.astype('float32')
y_true = K.constant(y_train)
y_pred = K.constant(layer_output)
g = K.categorical_crossentropy(target=y_true, output=y_pred)
g
# <tf.Tensor 'Neg_1:0' shape=(16327,) dtype=float32>
```

As you can see, the result `g` is a (Tensorflow) tensor, which needs to be evaluated:

```python
ce = K.eval(g)  # 'ce' for cross-entropy
type(ce)
# numpy.ndarray
ce.shape
# (16327,)
```

The result is a numpy array with the loss for each one of your 16,327 training samples.

Answer (score 1):

Your network is already being trained using `categorical_crossentropy`. To get the loss value on a dataset you can just use `model.evaluate`

```
values = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
```

Then `values[0]` will be the loss value and `values[1]` is the accuracy metric.

Comment: I reframe my question: In following code i want value of c, here a is true labes and b is predicted labels:                                                          `from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3])
b=np.array([1,1,1])
c=K.categorical_crossentropy(a, b)`.                                                          But getting error                                                                                            `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`